# Error instantiating the InteractiveSession using TensorFlow and Jupyter

Tags: python, ipython, tensorflow, jupyter

Recently I've been getting an error using the InteractiveSession in TensorFlow in my Jupyter / IPython notebook. The problem is so straight forward to recreate, my entire code is:

```
import tensorflow as tf

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

sess.graph
```

And the output is:

```
Exception ignored in: <bound method BaseSession.__del__ of <tensorflow.python.client.session.InteractiveSession object at 0x11a4e89b0>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/.../anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 140, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "/Users/.../anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 905, in close
    self._default_session.__exit__(None, None, None)
  File "/Users/brad/anaconda/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 66, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "/Users/.../anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3215, in get_controller
    assert self.stack[-1] is default
AssertionError: 
Out[3]:
<tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Graph at 0x10685dc50>
```

So the graph call works, but I can't interpret this error or get rid of it.

Comment: Which version of TensorFlow are you using? The interactive session destructor code was tweaked recently, and I haven't been able to recreate it with the latest version.

Comment: I'm using version v0.8.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message is caused by a bug in TensorFlow versions 0.8 and earlier. The bug is triggered when a new `tf.InteractiveSession` is created before an old one is deleted by the Python garbage collector. It was [fixed](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/aec225cbc1d6c2dd9ee51e09996a38c868e9e2dd) in TensorFlow version 0.9, so upgrading to the latest version should resolve the issue.